# Workflow when developing a packaged django application

Tags: python, django, setuptools

I'm trying to develop a django application to share with a project team. At this point, I have the alpha release of the application ready to share. Following the [instructions on how to package a django app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/reusable-apps/#packaging-your-app), I copied it to a separate folder, made all the files, and ran `setup.py`. It made my .zip file and all was good.

My confusion is, now that I did that, as per step (1) in the tutorial, my code is sitting outside my django project folder. How am I supposed to develop code if I can't easily run manage.py for migrate and runserver? Am I really expected to run setup.py, create a new package, and run `pip upgrade` every time I make a change?

In short, is there a way I can run setuptools while keeping the source code in the django folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-e` flag to `pip install` to install the project in editable/develop mode.

```
pip install -e path/to/my/source
```